# How to convert a very large Laravel application into static site?

Tags: laravel, performance, static-site

I've a really large Laravel application (hundreds of routes, thousands of possible pages etc). About three quarters of the pages don't change often (they change at max once in 2-3 months when the data is refreshed). The other 25% of the application is search, data that changes daily/weekly.

To improve speed, I'd like to explore the option of converting a large portion of the application into static sites. This will create thousands of HTML pages. Not sure if this is the best way to improve speed. If yes, how do I go about doing it? IF no, are there other options? Assuming that getting more RAM etc is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not an expert on this subject or know any tool that does that. What you intended to do is exactly like a Google bot that scan your entire page for any deep links and archive it into a memory.

What is needed to do is not simply get the pure HTML code source of the PHP output, but you need also to store dynamic contents generated by Javascript. Then hook to the site index page on page request, search if the page exists in the built cache folder and simply load it. Make sure to also build a system to invalidate the static cache too.

But first, try every other possible way such as Laravel cache, PHP OPCode cache and other server side cache level.